# Tesseract callback with Angular - 'this' is undefined

Tags: angular, tesseract.js

I am trying to get work Tesseract with Angular 2.

```
Tesseract.recognize(file)
    .progress(function (p) { console.log('progress', p) })
    .then(function (result) {
      this.resultText = result.text;
    })
}
```

The problem is on row:  **this.resultText = result.text;**.
I am getting error **'Cannot read property 'resultText' of undefined'**.

I am not sure why **this is undefined**.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *arrow function syntax* to bind `this` correctly in the callback

```
Tesseract.recognize(file)
    .progress((p) => { console.log('progress', p) })
    .then((result) => {
      this.resultText = result.text;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for more information
check this [video](https://youtu.be/hO7mzO83N1Q?list=WL&t=1444)

the issue you counter is lexical this reference.